# Pulling specific value from Pandas DataReader dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Here is the code I am running:

```
def competitor_stock_data_report():
    import datetime
    import pandas_datareader.data as web

    date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = date_time.date()

    stocklist = ['LAZ','AMG','BEN','LM','EVR','GHL','HLI','MC','PJT','MS','GS','JPM','AB']
    start = datetime.datetime(date.year-1, date.month, date.day-1)
    end = datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day-1)

    for x in stocklist:
        df = web.DataReader(x, 'google', start, end)
        print(df)
        print(df.loc[df['Date'] == start]['Close'].values)
```

The problem is in the last line. How do I pull the specific value of the date specified 'Close' value?

```
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
Date                                           
2016-08-02  35.22  35.25  33.66  33.75   861111
2016-08-03  33.57  34.72  33.42  34.25   921401
2016-08-04  33.89  34.22  33.77  34.07   587016
2016-08-05  34.55  34.94  34.31  34.35   463317
2016-08-08  34.54  34.75  34.31  34.74   958230
2016-08-09  34.68  35.12  34.64  34.87   732959
```

I would like to get `33.75` for example, but the date is dynamically changing..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: `df.loc[df.index[0], 'Close']`

Comment: Yes, this is perfect for the first value.. how about the last value.. like as if I am getting yesterday's price and then trying to get yesterday-a year ago's price? @MaxU What would I change the index value to in that case?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ gives me an error

Comment: Last row: `df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Close']`

Comment: You my friend are the man @MaxU

Comment: Are you aware that you can read all tickers in one step into Pandas.Panel: `p = web.DataReader(stocklist, 'google', start, end)` ;-)

Comment: Yes, not what I am looking for though. Appreciate it!

Comment: Do what @MaxU is suggesting.  I'd add use `at` instead of `loc` for scalar inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO the easiest way to get a column's value in the first row:

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
              Open    High     Low   Close   Volume
Date
2016-08-03  767.18  773.21  766.82  773.18  1287421
2016-08-04  772.22  774.07  768.80  771.61  1140254
2016-08-05  773.78  783.04  772.34  782.22  1801205
2016-08-08  782.00  782.63  778.09  781.76  1107857
2016-08-09  781.10  788.94  780.57  784.26  1318894
...            ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
2017-07-27  951.78  951.78  920.00  934.09  3212996
2017-07-28  929.40  943.83  927.50  941.53  1846351
2017-07-31  941.89  943.59  926.04  930.50  1970095
2017-08-01  932.38  937.45  929.26  930.83  1277734
2017-08-02  928.61  932.60  916.68  930.39  1824448

[252 rows x 5 columns]

In [41]: df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('Close')]
Out[41]: 773.17999999999995
```

Last row:

```
In [42]: df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Close')]
Out[42]: 930.38999999999999
```

Answer (score 4):

**Recommended**

- `df.at[df.index[-1], 'Close']`
- `df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Close')]`
- `df.loc[df.index[-1], 'Close']`
- `df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Close')]`

**Not intended as public api, but works**

- `df.get_value(df.index[-1], 'Close')`
- `df.get_value(-1, df.columns.get_loc('Close'), takeable=True)`

**Not recommended, chained indexing**
*There could be more, but do I really need to add them*

- `df.iloc[-1].at['Close']`
- `df.loc[:, 'Close'].iat[-1]`

All yield

```
34.869999999999997
```

Comment: Wow! this is comprehensive !